# UK visa refused for lack of strong ties to home country. How to reapply?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I applied for a visa to attend my graduation ceremony in the UK. I have clearly mentioned that, after the graduation, I will return to my country. I'm unemployed, just got out of college, and am dependent on my parents.

How to I convince them to issue a visa? I consider being unemployed as an unfair reason to refuse me. I can manage the funds issue; my concern is the first point in the letter.

What I need to do to improve the next application?

[image: Refusal]

[image: refusal2]

Comment: Thanks for the 1st page, can you do the 2nd page also? We need to see the grounds. I can see the problem pretty clearly, but need to know which parts of V 4.2 they cited at the end.

Comment: I am curious when did you graduate finish your coursework and when is the actual graduation date? Is this a case of you were financially sound enough to have been a student at the university but suddenly not enough to enter as a visitor? Were you an online student? Did you actually attend physically in the UK?

Comment: You seem to be expected visa granting to be fair. It might be nice if it were fair, but it isn't. In particular, there seems to be no place for arguing "I'm a law-abiding rule-following person. You admit me until date X, I'll be out of your country no later than X because that is the sort of person I am".

Comment: @SheikPaul many UK universities run overseas courses, where 90 to 100% of the tuition is carried out local to the students, by local faculty at a local college or university, but under supervision by the UK university, and the qualification is issued by the UK university.  They may never have set foot in the University of Bedfordshire before.  Typically you get an invite to a graduation ceremony in the UK, as its fairly prestigious.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Its worth noting that UK immigration officials try very hard to be fair - to the UK, that is.  They have no obligation to people applying to visit, but they have every obligation to UK tax payers to try and prevent illegal immigration.

Comment: If they refused on simple unemployment it WOULD be unfair, but they didn't. Please see http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3788/why-do-you-want-to-see-uk-refusal-notices

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: If you could _prove_ "I'm a law-abiding rule-following person", then it would probably go a long way towards a visa. Unfortunately merely _claiming_ this does not amount to much of a proof, because crooks can swear on that as easily as honest persons can. (But that's basically why proven performance in earlier travel helps).

Comment: My graduation date is 16march 2017. And it was distance learning course. How can I show my ties when Im still depending on my parents money.

Comment: @DonWee first step will be to post 2nd page of refusal Gayot has asked for, as we can only guess what were the grounds for refusal.

Comment: uploaded the 2nd page 
@GayotFow

Comment: @DonWee AHA!!! That clarifies it completely! They think you are going to overstay and look for work in the UK and then possibly work illegally.  There's the EXACT problem. However, it is still proportionality and provenance. Is the answer below satisfactory for you? Or do you need more answers?

Comment: @GayotFow So what should I do to attend my graduation? Its the most awaited day in my life. so.. what is your solution?

Comment: At the end of the day, my answer would not differ significantly from @o.m. 's answer below. Maybe a few tweaks and links. After seeing both pages (thanks for that), I suggest you "accept" the answer below and come to terms with the notion of being absent at the ceremony. Sorry to be the messenger of bad news, but it happens. Please be courteous and read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 9):

The third sentence of the first bullet point says "I am not satisfied you have strong ties to your home country."

- Find a stable, well-paid job at home. That's the most important factor.
- If you have dependents who do not travel with you, that *might* help. Unless the ECO believes that they're your reason to work in the UK.

You write that you consider your employment status an *unfair* reasony to deny you a visa. The UK disagrees, and they make the rules. You would be well advised not to raise the fairness issue in any communications with the UK entry clearance officers, because you must convince them that you will **abide by the rules**. Questioning their fairness doesn't help your position.

Comment: The unemployed part is just icing on the cake and not the root issue.  It's a combination of proportionality and provenance, but only knowing the actual grounds will tell us for sure.

Comment: My graduation date is 16march 2017. And it was distance learning course. How can I show my ties when Im still depending on my parents money.